# How to replace ' with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I try to use sed within a bash script in order to replace `'` with `''`
I have to do so because of an Oracle DB, but I cannot find the right syntax.

So far I have tried:

```
sed -e 's/(')/('')/g' List_employees_a.csv > List_employees.csv
sed -e 's/'/''/g' List_employees_a.csv > List_employees.csv
sed -e 's/'/\'\'/g' List_employees_a.csv > List_employees.csv
sed -e 's/\'/\''/g' List_employees_a.csv > List_employees.csv
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed 's/'\''/'\'''\''/g'
```

OR use double quoted for delimiters:

```
sed "s/'/''/g"
```

OR more verbose:

```
sq="'"
dq="''"
sed "s/$sq/$dq/g" file
```

Comment: It's two single quotes, not a double-quote. I made the same mistake.

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed. I wrote that : sed -e 's/'\''/'\'''\''/g'
I really had to have two single quotes instead of a double one.

Comment: @oz380: Sorry I interpreted `''` to be a double quote. In case you don't want to deal with crazy escaping you can use 2nd option of my answer.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: Thanks, realized and fixed.

Comment: Yo! I was also about to type the `tr` based answer to replace `'` to `"` :-)

Comment: `sed 's/'\''/&&/g' file` might be a little easier on the eye.

Comment: @potong: How about:  `sed "s/'/&&/g"`

Answer (score 4):

What about this one?

```
sed "s/'/''/g"
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
hello'my name is
quote' and double quote" blabla
$ sed "s/'/''/g" file
hello''my name is
quote'' and double quote" blabla
```

Comment: Thanks, @chepner! And also for the edit, I hadn't noticed it was `''` (two single quotes), I thought it was `"` (double quotes).

Comment: I missed it, too. My answer (using `$'...'`) got ugly after I fixed it, so I deleted it :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't sed, it's that your shell is parsing the quotes before they ever get to sed. One really easy way to avoid this is to use a script file:

```
sed -f script_file List_employees_a.csv > List_employees.csv
```

where the content of script_file is:

```
s/'/''/g
```

Answer (score 2):

In the single-quoted string notation in sh, the only special character is the single-quote `'` itself -- even backslash `\` is not special.  Juxtaposition is concatenation, so you can string together multiple string notations: `'foo''bar'` is the same as `"foobar"`, and `'foo'\''bar'` and `'foo'"'"'bar'` are both the same as "foo'bar".

You don't have to use single-quoted notation:

```
sed -e "s/'/\"/g"
```

But if you really want to, you can write

```
sed -e 's/'\''/"/g'
```

or

```
sed -e 's/'"'"'/"/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a sed expert so I am not sure what you try to achieve with (') etc. And you write in your comment that you need to replace ' with ", so why to you write ' ' in your attempts?

Anyway, I did some testing and a normal escape of the quotes did it for me. Hope it helps.

```
sed -e s/\'/\'\'/g List_employees_a.csv > List_employees.csv
```